# Pasar datos de un fichero a otro y eliminar el viejo

Tags: java

Estoy haciendo una transferencia de datos de un fichero a otro. Básicamente es pasar todos los nombres que sean diferentes de los que busco al nuevo fichero, sin utilizar Strings, solamente en algunos casos en los que ya se están usando.

Mi codigo:

```
public void borrar(String s) throws IOException {

    lleerFichero lf = new leerfichero("usuarios.txt"); 

    boolean igual = false;
    char[] nombre = lf.leerUsuario();

    while (nombre != null && !igual) {

        igual = true;
        //Miramos si el nombre es el mismo
        if (nombre.length == s.length()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {
                if (nombre[i] != s.charAt(i)) {
                    igual = false;
                }
            }
      //Si el tamaño es diferente, deducimos que no es el mismo nombre
        } else {
            igual = false;
        }

        //Si no es igual, escribimos en el fichero
        if (igual == true) {
        }
    }  
}
```

Método para leer un usuario:

```
    public char[] leerUsuario() throws IOException {
    String aux = br.readLine();
    System.out.println(aux);

//Tiene el " -1" porque el último caracter es una almuadilla (#) y no     quiero que la cuente.
    char[] nombre = new char[aux.length() - 1];

    for (int i = 0; i < nombre.length; i++) {
        nombre[i] = aux.charAt(i);
    }

    return nombre;
}
```

Entonces, mi problema es el siguiente: No se como crear un archivo nuevo, borrar el antiguo y al nuevo, ponerle el nombre del antiguo.

Además, a raíz de esto, me ha dado problemas. Por ejemplo, el programa ya no me escribe más en mi fichero .txt, no se por qué razón.

Estoy tratándolo con `Buffered/FileWritter i Buffered/FileReader`

Comment: Pues es que no has subido el código referente a la escritura ni lectura del fichero, con lo que a saber porqué pasa lo que dices que te pasa. Intenta acotar el problema y subir el código que te está dando problemas. Otra cosa: Para qué transformas los `String` en `char[]` en vez de trabajar con `String`? Para comparar objetos `String` no hay que comparar uno a uno todos los caracteres. Puedes usar `String.equals( String)`.

Comment: @SuperG280 no puedo utilizar Strings, solo los puedo utilizar para sacar datos del fichero (leer la linea)

Comment: Qué linea? En qué linea has puesto que no puedes usar String?? Será en la que no has escrito.

Comment: @SuperG280 en el programa en sí, es verdad que no lo he puesto, voy a cambiarlo